# sqoop-hive Import adding an extra column

Tags: oracle, import, hive, sqoop

I have imported data from `sqoop` to `hive` successfully. I have added an column in `Oracle` and again imported the particular column to `hive` using `sqoop-import`. But,it is appending to the first column data and remaining columns with null and no new column came in hive. Can anyone resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With out looking at your `import` statements, I am assuming that in your second import you are trying to append to the existing import but only importing new column using `--columns` and `--append` arguments. It will not work this way as it will append to the file at end of the file not at end of the each line.

you will need to overwrite the existing data in hdfs using `--hive-overwrite`; and alter hive table for adding additional column. OR just drop the hive table and use `--create-hive-table` in sqoop command.

so you `import` command should look like this:

```
 sqoop --import \
       --connect $CONNECTION_STR \ 
       --username $USER \
       --password $PASS \
       --table $ORACLE_TABLE \
       --hive-import \
       --hive-overwrite \
       --hive-table \
       --hive-home $HIVE_HOME \
       --hive-table $HIVE_TABLE
```

*Change values to actual values of your environment*

Comment: I Think "--hive-overwrite" this will delete the entire table and again reimport it Right? which leads to Performance ISSUE.

Comment: Agreed but you won't be adding columns everyday right. This would once in year or may be in month. I don't see any other direct sqoop option available that would achieve your requirements.

Comment: And also hdfs doesn't allows modifying files but allows appending - so sqoop won't be able to do modifications. If you append thn existing data will not have added column values